# Weird XML parsing error

Tags: php, eclipse, firefox, xml-parsing, wampserver

All,

I'm writing PHP on Eclipse and using Wampserver to view my code on Firefox.  I'm encountering a weird error.  Here is an example of the code that produces the error:

```
<?php
 header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
 echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
 $stringResult='ABC';
 echo $stringResult;
?>
```

This gives me the Firefox yellow screen of death and the following message:

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: http://localhost/Tests/2013.09_xml_parsing_error/
Line Number 1, Column 40:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>ABC
----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

(Note that on Firefox the `-----^` points straight after `..."utf-8" ?>`)

What's causing this?

**EDIT:**  I'm also getting an error if I just write:

```
<?php
 header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
 $stringResult='ABC';
 echo $stringResult;
?>
```

I get the following error:

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: http://localhost/Tests/2013.09_xml_parsing_error/
Line Number 1, Column 1:ABC
^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to send valid xml, which requires a root node, something like

```
<?php
 header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
 echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
 $stringResult='<letters>ABC</letters>';
 echo $stringResult;
?>
```

Comment: I see.  So if I just want to write some php what should I start my code with - just the header?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: That page will be the URL called in an Ajax call.  So it's never displayed.  Should I just remove the header and write `echo 'ABC';`, or should I leave the header and write `echo'<body>ABC</body>';`?

Comment: If you're expecting an xml response, if not then just send the bare data.

Answer (score 1):

It points to a wrong xml attribute. Since your string is not a attribute